# Access nested attributes in values_list()

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure if I worded this right, but I have extended Django's User model, with my 'UserProfile' model, using

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
```

and I want to access all combined attributes of both User and UserProfile, by using something like this:

```
UserProfile.objects.all().values_list('someAttr', 'user.otherAttr')
```

But as I realised I can't access nested attributes like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double underscore

```
UserProfile.objects.values_list('someAttr', 'user__otherAttr')
#                                                ^^^
```